# Pass logged in user in CRM as a parameter to IFRAME

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-4

In MS Dynamics CRM 4.0 we have created an extra tab for the salesorder entity in which an IFRAME with a custom, remote PHP page is loaded. Is there any way to find out which CRM user opened the tab with the IFRAME from the PHP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use postMessage to send the user's information to the IFRAME. This works even if the IFRAME is on an other domain (cross domain). postMessage is supported in:

- Internet Explorer 8.0+
- Firefox 3.0+
- Safari 4.0+
- Google Chrome 1.0+
- Opera 9.5+

Resources:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc197015(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/18/postmessage-in-html5-to-send-messages-between-windows-and-iframes/

Comment: Thanks, this works. Do you know how I can retrieve information about the logged on user in CRM using JS?

Comment: To get information regarding the current user you'll need to write Javascript: https://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/hardworkdays/archive/2011/07/24/crm-4-0-function-which-returns-current-user-lookup.aspx